# how can I link a list to if else? Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, arraylist

I don't understand exactly why I always get an error here. I have built a (if else) statement, in a short version. Whenever the function no longer finds a value, i.e. comes to 3 in the array, I get the error that there is no more data in the array / list. But I did install an (ELSE) and it should display the text ("HELLO"). I don't know exactly where the error is. Maybe someone can help me briefly, thank you.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tasktolean/body.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var bodyTextIndex = 0;
  var bodytext = [
    'Hello FIRST Text!',
    'Hello SECOND Text!',
    'Hello THIRD Text!',
  ];

  void buttonPress() {
    setState(() {
      bodyTextIndex = bodyTextIndex + 1;
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'TASK',
          ),
        ),
        body: bodyTextIndex <= bodytext.length
            ? Column(
                children: [
                  BodyTextChance(
                    bodytext[bodyTextIndex],
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: buttonPress,
                    child: Text(
                      'CLICK ME',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            : Center(
                child: Text('HELLO'),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> 
> 
> class BodyTextChance extends StatelessWidget {   String bodytext;
> 
>   BodyTextChance(this.bodytext);
> 
>   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Text(bodytext);   } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

This line uses a wrong comparison operator:

```
body: bodyTextIndex <= bodytext.length
```

It should use `<` operator like so:

```
body: bodyTextIndex < bodytext.length
```

#### A Bit More Details

When `bodyTextIndex` becomes 3, the condition below is still met:

```
bodyTextIndex <= bodytext.length
```

Then it refers to `bodytext[3]` but the element doesn't exist because it ranges from 0 to 2.

Comment: How do you actually know which operator you can use?

Comment: It really depends, but I would generally use < operator unless it improves the readability to use <=.